# Call jQuery code in Telerik button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, telerik

I have a jQuery that creates a prompt box to get the password in the form of ***. This my code:

```
$(function () {
  password = $("#password"),
  allFields = $([]).add(password),
  tips = $(".validateTips");
  function updateTips(t) {
    tips
      .text(t)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout(function () {
      tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    }, 500);
  }
  function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
    if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
    if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
      o.addClass("ui-state-error");
      updateTips(n);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Enter": function () {
        var bValid = true;
        allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
        bValid = bValid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);
        // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez:
        // http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
        bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");
        if (password.val() != "1234") {
          return false;
        }
        if (password.val() == "1234") {
          window.location.href = './Frm_Device.aspx';
          alert("1234 ast");
          if (bValid) {
            $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>");
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return true;
          }
        }
      },
      Exit: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function () {
      allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
  });
  $("#create").button().click(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

And I have a Telerik Button. I want to know how I should call jQuery in this button.

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="create" runat="server" Text="RadButton"
  AutoPostBack="False"  ToolTip="combined data recovered from the Teams"
  class="create" OnClientClicked="?">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

In the above code, instead of ?, what should I put?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OnClientClicked takes the name of the JavaScript function that will be executed. This means you need a named function, inside that you can execute your code. More on how to handle client-side handlers can be found here:
http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/button/passing-user-defined-parameters-to-client-side-event-handlers.aspx
and
here
http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/12-08-10/migrating-onclientclick-handlers-from-asp-button-to-telerik-s-asp-net-ajax-button.aspx